# Loading Different Gridview Dynamically on each Button Click

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a scenario in which a screen has 5 buttons, on click of each button a different grid view should be loaded.

eg: btn1 clicked grdv1 should be loaded,
    btn2 clicked grdv2 should be loaded.

How can i achieve the above, 
***Condition*** is that the load on the page during each postback should be less or min.

I had done it using *iFrame*, loading separate aspx pages to iFrame on each btn click, but i cant get the control id's within the gridview loaded, as i need to do operations on the loaded grid.

Can some1 help me out with a simplest solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If both the gridviews have same columns then on button click bind corresponding data. If the columns are different then On PageLoad method set all gridview's attribute i.e visible = "false" except the first one.  In OnBtnClick_ForGvn make the corresponding gridview visible by gvn.visible = true;. Hope it helps.

Comment: Ya we can do that but every time the page loads all the grid view will be loaded at ones.
Which i want to eliminate.
so their wont be much load on page load each time.